# Writing wi-fi device driver in Android

Tags: android, wifi, linux-device-driver, android-wifi

I want to write a wi-fi driver. My problem is, that on run time I want to switch between the original wi-fi driver to my wi-fi driver and vice versa.
Can it be done?

Comment: why do you need your own driver when there already is a default android driver?

Comment: I want to change the wifi driver according to my needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might hack wpa_supplicant, pass a new command from the Android UI, which let's wpa_supplicant unload the old kernel module and load the new one.

Just my five cents, thought.